# Tensorflow - Does data adjancency matter ? - MNIST example

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, mnist

I looked at the [MNIST example](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#mnist-for-ml-beginners) and noticed that when the array of the image is flattened into a 728 array, would it matter if that array was randomized? I mean does the NN take into account the adjacency of the data, or is there one input node put input number (therefore 728 nodes).

What I am asking is, will I get the same network if I train with the images flattened as in the example, as I would if I randomised the 728 data array ?

Comment: Yes, it takes it into account and it helps. Some people got bored with MNIST and try to see how well you can do if you are not able to use the data layout. For that they flatten images into random order 1D arrays (but same random order for each image) so that network can't take advantage of any pre-determined structure. Search for "permutation invariant MNIST" and "permutation invariant SVHN"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on which mnist example you're looking at.  convolutional.py runs a 5x5 spatial convolutional window across the image, which does take into account spatial correlation.

The MNIST for beginners example that uses a simple weight matrix:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
```

does not.  You could permute the order of entries in the points and not change anything, *as long as you permute all inputs the same way*.

(There's a reason that convolutional approaches are winning for most image recognition applications -- spatial locality *is* useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the very basic tutorial, whose whole point is to familiarize you with TF and a couple of important ML concepts which would be used in many harder models. They are not trying to do anything hard (in fact the accuracy is not higher than what you would achieve by running SVM out of the box). If you read the tutorial carefully they say:

> It doesn't matter how we flatten the array, as long as we're
>   consistent between images.

and

> Flattening the data throws away information about the 2D structure of
>   the image. Isn't that bad? Well, the best computer vision methods do
>   exploit this structure, and we will in later tutorials. But the simple
>   method we will be using here, a softmax regression, won't.

Your question about the network: the topology of the network would be the same, the weights/biases would be different.

Also an example with [convolutional neural network](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.md) takes into the account the adjacency of the data